# Issues with launching a remote process from C#

Tags: c#, process, wmi, rpc

I'm using [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx) to launch a remote application on another domain machine.

Unfortunately, if the remote process is already running, but in the background of the remote machine's desktop, the application does not gain focus using Process.Start.

**Question 1:** Is there another API or mechanism to force the remote application to gain focus, or flash to get the user's attention?

The other issue I noticed, is if the remote process is already running, a new instance may be executed in addition to the original. This violates MSDN's documentation which says:

> "If the process is already running, no additional process resource is started. Instead, the existing process resource is reused and no new Process component is created. In such a case, instead of returning a new Process component, Start returns null to the calling procedure."

**Question 2:** Has anyone found a way to prevent a second instance of the application from launching in this case? Is WMI a better choice to use for remote launching of applications?

Comment: Can you modify the code of the app you're trying to invoke (or are willing to)?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's a 3rd-party microscope controller / image recorder. My setup is a geology lab with 2 HP TouchSmart PCs. My app runs on the left-hand monitor, and when the user clicks/touches a Microscope button, it would ideally launch (or bring forward) this 3rd party app on the right-hand monitor.

Comment: Oh well i was about to suggest the Mutex class as a way to ensure no more than 1 instance of the app run at once. But if you can't modify it then MY hands are tied.

Comment: I'm assuming you already considered a small helper application on the second machine?

Comment: @ChrisB, actually no I had not. It seems like a feasible approach... but in that app, what's the API to set focus to my desired target app? It seems like the I have the same problem.

Comment: Well, the helper program could check to see if the process is already started (something like http://www.vcskicks.com/single-instance.php).  One bit of the problem solved

Comment: @retrodrone - using PInvokes to the Win32 api will let you do just about whatever you want with window focus, locations etc - mazzzzz's answer below is a good example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, don't know how well this will work for you, but it is an example class that you could use in the helper program.  This is only the start, if you plan on using it, you will need a networking system (not to bad with C# though).  Tell me how it works for you.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows you to start a specified program, or if it is already running, bring it into focus
/// </summary>
static class SFProgram
{
    static public void StartFocus(string FileName, string ProcessName)
    {
        if (!ProcessStarted(ProcessName))
            Process.Start(FileName);
        else
            SFProgram.BringWindowToTop("notepad");
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Bring specified process to focus
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="windowName">Process Name</param>
    /// <returns>If it was successful</returns>
    private static bool BringWindowToTop(string windowName)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(windowName);
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            int hWnd = (int)p.MainWindowHandle;
            if (hWnd != 0)
            {
                return SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)hWnd);
            }
            //p.CloseMainWindow();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool ProcessStarted(string ProcessName)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
        return (processes.Length > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I haven't had a chance to try it yet. Maybe tomorrow. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, I would have preferred to point you in the right direction (hate just writing something for someone), but this seems like a small part of the helper program.

Comment: My implementation works beautiful, thanks @mazzzzz. I beefed up the Process.Start to require user credentials. I don't need random code running on the target. Thanks!